# How to find the frequency of $F(t)=c_{1} sin(2 \pi t)+c_{2} cos(2 \pi t)$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to find the frequency of $F(t)$? I have calculated it numerically and it seems that $F(t)$ also has a frequency of $2\pi$, but how to prove it mathematically?
\begin{equation}
F(t)=c_1\sin(2 \pi t)+c_2\cos(2 \pi t)
\end{equation}

Comment: If you know $F(t)$ then what is the problem?

Comment: Adding sinusoids with the same frequency, if:  $$g(t) = \sum_{k} c_k ~ \cos(\omega t + p_k)$$ then $$g(t) = M\cos(\omega t + Q)$$ where $$\begin{align} V &= \sum_{k} c_k ~\angle~ p_k \\ M &= |V| \\ Q &= \text{angle}~V \end{align}$$ and $\angle$ is polar coordinates.

Comment: Put them together as a single sinusoidal function and you can show this.

Comment: Btw, the frequency is $1$, not $2\pi$.

Comment: Hint : $\sin(A+B) = \sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know Euler's formula, then you can do:

$$\begin{align}
c_1 \cos(\omega t) + c_2 \sin(\omega t) 
%
&= c_1 \cos(\omega t + 0) + c_2 \cos(\omega t - \pi/2) \\
%
&= {\mathcal R}\left(c_1 e^{ i \omega t}\right) 
 + {\mathcal R}\left(c_2 e^{ i \omega t - i \pi/2}\right) \\
%        
&= {\mathcal R}\left(c_1 e^{ i \omega t} + c_2 e^{ i \omega t - i \pi/2}\right) \\
%
&= {\mathcal R}\left(e^{i \omega t} \left(c_1 + c_2 e^{- i \pi/2}\right)\right) \\
%
&= {\mathcal R}\left(e^{i \omega t} Me^{iQ}\right) \\
%
&= {\mathcal R}\left(M e^{i \omega t + Q}\right) \\
%
&= M\cos(\omega t + Q) \\
%
\end{align}$$

So the frequency is still $\omega / (2\pi)$.

Comment: thanks! that looks magical for me.

Comment: @zlin For a more intuitive explanation, consider playing a C# on one piano and then a C# on another piano.  The notes will have a different volume: magnitude, that's the $c_k$.  They will have a different phase since they weren't started at the same time, $\sin$ and $\cos$ are the same except for phase.  But do you expect 2 instruments playing a C# to combined result in a different note?  No, the frequency doesn't change.

Comment: thanks. It is a very good explanation!